# Upgraded site from EE1 to EE2 but data in exp_matrix_data missing

Tags: matrix

As the title says, I've upgraded a site from EE1 to EE2 but data that I can see exists for entries in exp_matrix_data table is missing from the publish page, i.e. there's rows in exp_matrix_data whose entry_id column matches up with entries that should have matrix data, but when viewing the entry in the CP, Matrix says there's no rows yet.

Anyone come across that before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what the problem is. The is_draft column was missing so I had to create it manually. All the legacy rows had their value for that column set to NULL instead of 0. Updating to 0 brings back the data.

I had a problem with is_draft missing throwing a MySQL error but the previous time, I just clicked into the fieldtypes settings and it went away. This time it didn't do it which is why I created the column manually.

Comment: Glad you figured that out!  Sometimes hitting submit on the license page also helps to fix this up.

Comment: Yeah, I did that too.

Comment: But you're up and running now? If so, can you mark your answer as official?  And thank you for posting what you had to do to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

Is all matrix data missing? Can you add a new matrix row? Does the other data appear? If not, i suggest compare whats different with the exp_matrix_data rows. And check exp_channel_data, there will be a matrix field their too. And if you have copied in the database tables, have you enabled the matrix module, or installed the latest version.

Comment: What version of Matrix are you running?

Comment: EE 2.5.5, Matrix 2.5.3